# Display Template Render HTML in list item

Tags: 2013, search-results, content-query-web-part, display-template

I am building a display template for a CSWP. One of the properties is a multi-lined  textbox and some HTML is stored with the actual data. How do I go about rendering this html in my display template?

**Sample Data**

```
<div class="ExternalClassAE8F3DF56FC4439E9AA218A73E8A5409">
    <p>
    ​    <span style="color&#58;#000000;font-family&#58;arial, helvetica, sans;font-size&#58;11px;
line-height&#58;14px;text-align&#58;justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id 
est laborum.
        </span>
        ​​<br>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Currently how is it getting rendered? With HTML formatting or without?

Comment: Plain text. No HTML formatting

Comment: ExceptionLimeCat - You mean you don't want any HTML formatting to be applied to the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use following code in the display template

```
<div title="_#= $htmlEncode(line4.defaultValueRenderer(line4)) =#_" id="_#= line4Id =#_">
    _#=STSHtmlDecode(line4.value)=#_
</div>
```

Source - https://ingessharepointnotes.wordpress.com/2014/03/04/sharepoint-display-templates-display-enhanced-rich-text-field/

Another example

```
var desc = $getItemValue(ctx, "Description");
_#= STSHtmlDecode(desc.value) =#_
```

Source - http://rwcchen.blogspot.com/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-working-with-display.html